# $V\cap \Sigma$ homeomorphic to a disc

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, dynamical-systems

> Let $X:U\subset\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ a complete vector field of class $\mathscr{C}^k$($k\geqslant 1$), $p$ a regular point for $X$,$\varphi(t,p)$ a solution curve that goes through $p$ and $\Sigma$ a local cross -section of $X$ that passes through $p$. Assume that $\varphi(T,p)\in\Sigma$ for a $T>0$.
>
> Show there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $p$ and a diffeomorphism  over $\pi$ such that for every $\Sigma_0=V\cap\Sigma$ is homeomorphic to a disc  and contains p, and $\pi(x)\in \Sigma$ is the first return of point x to the section $\Sigma$.

I think I could use the Flow box theorem so that it would give a diffeormphism let's say $\psi:V\to(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\times B$. However I am not sure and I do not know how to formalize that proof.

I am stuck at this problem as I do not have any idea on how to solve it.

**Question**:

How should I solve the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your definition for "local cross section"?  And, what does the phrase "... a diffeomorphism over $\pi$..." mean?

Comment: Probably you know the implicit function theorem. What is your difficulty?

Comment: @Mnifldz It is a transversal section.

Comment: @JohnB Thanks for your answer. I do not know how to apply the implicit function theorem on this case. Could you please show me? I need to see an example on how to solve these sort of questions.

Comment: Then you can have a look at the proof of the flow box theorem.

Comment: @JohnB              That could give me the diffeomorphism I guess, but I still would need prove $V\cap\Sigma$ is homeomorphic to a disc. I have no idea on how to tackle that problem.